# SSH connection timing out with Google Cloud

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, timeout, putty

I'm pretty new to servers/cloud computing so please bear with me.

Instance image: windows-server-1809-dc-core-for-containers-v20200908

My issue is that when I try to connect through SSH to my instance, the Putty client keeps timing out. But I can access the instance through Remote Desktop Connection just fine.

I have already configured the public and private keys as detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys?hl=en_US).I have already added exceptions to the Firewall and tried disabling it alltogether.
This is my relevant Putty config:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The whole reason I'm trying to connect via Putty is that I want to use X11 forwarding (with Xming) to run remotely a program with GUI. I'm trying to run Stata 16. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have SSH enabled server-side. Here's the [web-page](https://www.concurrency.com/blog/february-2019/getting-started-with-ssh-on-windows-server-2019) with the relevant info on how to do this.

By default GCP Windows images do not have the SSH agent pre-installed. You will need to manually install the SSH agent